# JDBC4/MySQL syntax error: when retrieving data from mysql table

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Is there anything wrong in the code below?

String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM REGCUSTOMERS" + "WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

I'm trying to get the data from the username and password column of REGCUSTOMERS table.

*Eclipse Error:*

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ? AND password = ?' at line 1

```
 private boolean isAuthenticated(String userid, String password) {

    // JDBC logic to verify from database.

    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM REGCUSTOMERS" + "WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        if (rs.getString("username") != userid && rs.getString("password") != password) {

            return false;
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have no space between REGCUSTOMERS and WHERE. Add the space and you should be fine:

```
    String sql = "SELECT username, password FROM REGCUSTOMERS " + "WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
```

Comment: Yes, so MysQL is seeing `FROM REGCUSTOMERSWHERE username` and thinks that `username` is an alias for the nonexistent table `REGCUSTOMERSWHERE`. Then the `=` comes out of place.

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
... FROM REGCUSTOMERS" + "WHERE username ...
```

Will result in the following SQL:

```
FROM REGCUSTOMERSWHERE
```

That of course is wrong.

The `+` doesn't make sense there, but if you want it, you need a space at least on one side

```
"... FROM REGCUSTOMERS " + "WHERE username ..."
```